# Safari Browser has troubles with Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Safari()  
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']"))).send_keys("username")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']").send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button/div[text()='Log In']").click()
```

Ran the code above in hopes it would finally work and fill in the instagram login page. However, it returns this error...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d0556cce8de8> in <module>
      6 driver = webdriver.Safari()
      7 driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
----> 8 WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']"))).send_keys("username")
      9 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']").send_keys("password")
     10 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button/div[text()='Log In']").click()

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     78             if time.time() > end_time:
     79                 break
---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     81 
     82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

TimeoutException: Message:
```

Tried this on Chrome as well, but I still got the same message. Any clue as to what's going on? Below is the HTML for the username block.

```
<label class="f0n8F "><span class="_9nyy2">Phone number, username, or email</span><input aria-label="Phone number, username, or email" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="75" name="username" type="text" class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" value=""></label>
```

Below is the HTML for the password block.

```
<label class="f0n8F "><span class="_9nyy2">Password</span><input aria-label="Password" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" name="password" type="password" class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" value=""></label>
```

Comment: Try increasing the time higher than 10 seconds and see what happens.

Comment: @arundeepchohan I increased it to 20 and still got the same message.

Comment: @arundeepchohan There might be a problem with my mac so I'm gonna use a different one and see what happens then. I need to get this laptop cleaned haha